# Проблемы с кириллицей в базе данных firebird

Tags: firebird

Я работаю с бд firebird в ibeexprt и у меня возникли проблемы с кириллицей. Вместо букв-какие то "кракозябры".[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите следующие параметры: 1) charset базы 2) charset столбца name 3) Font Characters Set в свойствах подключения IBExpert 4) сharset в свойствах подключения к БД программы которая вставляла данные в таблицу (если это было сделано не в IBExpert )